# How to construct class that can replace typedef vector<vector<T>> Type

Tags: c++, class, c++11, construct

I am learning classes in C++ and would like to construct my own class instead of using a 2D vector "`typedef vector<vector<T>> C_type`". I have some code written:

```cpp
class T {
    public:
    int a;
    int b;
    T(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b){}

};
```

Now I have:

```cpp
typedef vector<vector<T>> C_type;
```

I'd like to use a class instead and create a constructor and initialize it, something like:

```cpp
class C_type {
vector<vector<T>> name;
C_type();}
C_type::C_type(){name = vector<vector<T>>(..........
```

I'd like to use the 2D vector as a class member. Thanks.

Comment: Yea.. I figured it out. I’m learning classes and trying things. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's something simple to start with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class C_type {
public:
    C_type(int rows, int cols) : _vec(std::vector<std::vector<T>>(rows, std::vector<T>(cols))) {}
    C_type() : C_type(0, 0) {}

    T get(int row, int col) { return this->_vec.at(row).at(col); }
    void set(int row, int col, T value) { this->_vec.at(row).at(col) = value; }

    size_t rows() { return this->_vec.size(); }
    size_t cols() { return this->_vec.front().size(); }

private:
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> _vec;
};

int main() {

    C_type<int> c(2, 2);

    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < c.rows(); ++i ) {
        for ( unsigned j = 0; j < c.cols(); ++j ) {
            c.set(i, j, i + j);
        }   
    }

    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < c.rows(); ++i ) {
        for ( unsigned j = 0; j < c.cols(); ++j ) {
            std::cout << c.get(i, j) << " ";
        }   
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```